# Concavity of the function $|f|$ , while $f$ is concave

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Prove or disprove, "if $f$ is concave function, then $|f|$ is also concave".

I know the result is false for conves function, but for concave function, I guess it is true. But I am unable to do the proof.

I have tried to show that the set $A=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 :|f(x)|\ge y\}$ is a convex set.
For this, take two points $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2) \in A$ and take $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Now, $|f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)|\ge f(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)\ge \lambda f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)f(x_2)$, as $f$ is concave. From this how to proceed?
Can I get any help please?

Comment: Have you tried simple examples?

Comment: What about $1-x^2$?

Comment: If you know the result for convex functions just apply to $g=-f$ which is convex....

Comment: I suggest that on a convex open subset $\Omega$, $f$ and $\lvert f\rvert$ are both concave if and only if $f$ is concave and either $f$ is affine and $f\le 0$ on $\Omega$, or $f> 0$ on $\Omega$.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: $f(x)=x$ is concave, but $|f(x)|=|x|$ is convex (and it is not concave).

Comment: More importantly, $x\mapsto |x|$ is not concave. (Concave and convex are not negations of each other)

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:

Note that
$$
f(x) = - x^2, \ \ \ (x \in \mathbf{R})
$$
is a concave function, but
$$
 | f(x) | = x^2, \ \ \ (x \in \mathbf{R})
$$
is a convex function.